# Getting an error Run time erro 9, Subscript Out of Range

Tags: vba, excel, vb6

I am getting this run-time error 9 , Subscript Out of range in Excel VBA 2003 while creating charts,

Somewhere in the code, `Public Chrt_color As Variant` and also
   `'Assigning the chart colors
      Chrt_color = Array(4, 7, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 17, 18, 21, 22, 23, 3, 43, 51, 50, 39, 47, 52,        56)`

```
Public Sub label_creation_Chart5(ByRef wksht As Excel.Worksheet)


Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer
Dim iTemp As Integer
Dim cht_Num As Integer
Dim iTextBoxLoc As Integer
Dim dbTemp As Double
Dim vSeriesValues As Variant
Dim dbSeriesLastValue() As Double


Application.ScreenUpdating = False
cht_Num = 5

wksht.ChartObjects("Chart 5").Activate
wksht.ChartObjects("Chart 5").Select

Do While ActiveChart.TextBoxes.Count > 0
    ActiveChart.TextBoxes(1).Delete
Loop

If ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.Count < 1 Then GoTo Sub_end

ReDim dbSeriesLastValue(1 To ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.Count) As Double
ReDim iSeriesIndex(1 To ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.Count) As Integer

For i = 1 To ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.Count
    vSeriesValues = ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(i).Values

    If wksht.Range("AJ" & (i + 52)).Value = "Yes" Or _
       (prdName = "" And InStr(wksht.Range("A" & (i + 52)).Value, corpName) > 2) Then
        ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(i).Border.ColorIndex = 5
        wksht.Range("Z" & (i + 52) & ":AH" & (i + 52)).Font.ColorIndex = 5
    Else
        ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(i).Border.ColorIndex = Chrt_color(i)
        wksht.Range("Z" & (i + 52) & ":AH" & (i + 52)).Font.ColorIndex = Chrt_color(i)
    End If

    dbSeriesLastValue(i) = vSeriesValues(UBound(vSeriesValues, 1))
    iSeriesIndex(i) = i
    iTextBoxLoc = 12 + 202 * (1 - (vSeriesValues(UBound(vSeriesValues, 1)) / (ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).MaximumScale - ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).MinimumScale)))
    With ActiveChart.TextBoxes.Add(195, iTextBoxLoc, 100, 13)
        .AutoSize = True
        .Text = ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(i).Name
        With .Font
            .Name = "Arial"
            .Size = 7
            .ColorIndex = ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(i).Border.ColorIndex
        End With
    End With
Next i
For i = 1 To (ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.Count - 1)
    For j = i + 1 To ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.Count
        If dbSeriesLastValue(j) < dbSeriesLastValue(i) Then
            dbTemp = dbSeriesLastValue(j)
            dbSeriesLastValue(j) = dbSeriesLastValue(i)
            dbSeriesLastValue(i) = dbTemp
            iTemp = iSeriesIndex(j)
            iSeriesIndex(j) = iSeriesIndex(i)
            iSeriesIndex(i) = iTemp
        End If
    Next j
Next i
```

I am getting the error at `ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(i).Border.ColorIndex = Chrt_color(i)`
Also value of `ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(i).Border.ColorIndex = -4105` is showing in intermediate window when the error occurs.

Please help!

Comment: Have you tried single-stepping through the code? The error message indicates that you're trying to use an array index that is not available.

Comment: Yeah I have, Its showing error at `ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(i).Border.ColorIndex = Chrt_color(i)`.

Comment: So, is `i` a valid index for `Chrt_color`? And if so, is `Chrt_colo(i)` a valid index for the `ColorIndex` collection?

Comment: `Chrt_color = Array(4,  7, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 17, 18, 21, 22, 23, 3, 43, 51, 50, 39, 47, 52, 56)`   Also how can I check if its a valid index for colorIndex collection? I am New to VBA and running someone else code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd look at the value of i when you get the error message.  Your code iterates i from to the number of series.   Say you had more series than the elements of Chtr_color, then Chrt_color(i) doesn't evaluate beyond.

Another problem might be the series index goes from 1 to N while the array index goes from 0 to N-1.

Comment: i=21 when the error occurs. Also I tried increasing the size of array to 25 elements but still didnt work.

Comment: 56 is a legal value and It seems that ActiveChart.SeriesCollection does conatin an element

Comment: Hi there, Solved the problem by changing the inout data. Thanks guys for help!

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the original question and comments, everything looks perfect. I have a couple of suggestions and questions tho:

*It seems that ActiveChart.SeriesCollection does conatin an element*.

**1.Are you not sure? Have you not checked in the watch window?**

*'Assigning the chart colors Chrt_color = Array(4, 7, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 17, 18, 21, 22, 23, 3, 43, 51, 50, 39, 47, 52, 56)*

**2.This most likely may not be the reason but do check if the single quote is active and if so, this line becomes commented out rendering the array empty.**